# Unity XR Spectator Camera

Tags: unity, 3d, rendering, virtual-reality, oculus

I would like to have a VR camera (for the player) but also have another camera (spectator).

I am using Unity 2019.4.8f1 on the Universal Render Pipeline

I have only been able to find outdated articles:

https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/12/12/spectating-vr/

https://unity3d.college/2017/05/08/unity3d-spectator-mode-vr/

https://forum.unity.com/threads/using-a-second-cam-while-still-rendering-the-vr-camera-for-the-vr-headset.659434/

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried, based on your research so far? How do the results of your experiments so far differ from what you need?

Comment: @DMGregory I cannot find the `Target Eye` option in the inspector, presumably because I am using URP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the "Target Eye" property now hides from the Inspector unless you change it via a script at runtime.

```
camera.stereoTargetEye = StereoTargetEyeMask.None;
```

Which causes to correctly take over the desktop display without rendering in the HMD.

Answer (score 0):

I get a 2nd camera output in unity by using [KlakSpout](https://github.com/keijiro/KlakSpout) (requires URP and Unity 2020+).

It re-routes a camera to [VPT8](https://hcgilje.wordpress.com/vpt/) - which displays full screen on my 2nd monitor - where I can record it with [OBS](https://obsproject.com/).

This way I have the VR headset for my immersive experience, and I can record a motion-smoothed version of my POV or a 3rd person - or static - can put the 2nd camera anywhere.